# Best practice to run `servr::rmd2()` in background/forever

Tags: r, nohup

I'm planning to use [servr::rmdv2()](http://10.12.16.169:4321) to host some Rmarkdown generated files on a CentOS 6.3 server. I'm wondering what the suggested best practice is for keeping this running in the background, and preferably restarting when my server restarts. Some options I'm considering

1. Run in background `Rscript ... $`. Won't restart.
2. Run in a `screen` session. Not sure that this will automatically restart.
3. Use `nohup Rscript ...` or `nohup servr` with the servr provided shell script. Place command in `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` so it runs when system restarts.

Any other options? I'm thinking #3 is the way to go but haven't done anything like this before so not sure what issues I may run into.

Comment: Fourth option ... use Dirk's `littler` package.

Comment: Thanks @42- I've seen littlr but never taken time to learn it's functionality. Will look into it next...

Answer (score 0):

I settled on option #3 (`hohup Rscript ...`). To take care of making sure it's running, I put this command in `crontab` to run hourly and use [flock](https://serverfault.com/questions/82857/prevent-duplicate-cron-jobs-running/82863#82863) to make sure that the cron job only restarts if the job isn't currently running.